# How do i read and write to the same file in scala?

Tags: scala, io, scala-collections, scala-2.10, read-write

So Im trying to read a text file in scala and whenever and I see a certain symbol I want to write something onto the text file at that certain point in the text file.

for example I am reading a file which contains :

> **Hi my name is "", and this is a text file.**

So while reading the file I want to write something to it when i see the symbol ""; how would i go along doing this in scala?

Comment: It won't work that easily. When the file is loaded to the memory, the constituent bytes of its content are located in consecutive memory cells (not really, but close enough). When you write new content in the apostrophes, you override the next bytes. So if you would do that the naive way and wrote "Alan", you'd end up with `Hi my name is "Alannd this is a text file.`You should read the file to a buffer, operate on that and then overwrite the file. By the way because of you I used insert key for the first time since five years ago. The bloody thing still works!

Comment: I would recommend you to read from one file (you can do it lazy in Scala with `Source.fromFile(...).getLines` which returns iterator) and write into another one

Comment: Can you read each line process it and write to other file , and then delete the old one ,and rename the new file ?

Comment: 1. Why do you want to discard the input file?  2. Why can't you just do the substituion `"" => something` while you write the file? 3. Do you plan for any other substituions? Looks like a small template engine is what you are looking for.

Comment: my end goal really is to create an obfuscater, so then I will be replacing variables within a file but also added, so im just trying to get ideas for the best way to do this in scala as im new to it

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still relevant: you may be interested in Java's `FileChannel`, which allows you to read and write to arbitrary byte offsets in a File.

Oracle even provides an example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html), which, in scala, boils down to:

```
val fc = FileChannel.open(filePath, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)

fc.read(destinationBuffer, position) // read bytes from the specified position
fc.write(sourceBuffer, position)     // write bytes to a specified position
```